# Deploy java web service without using web server

Tags: java, web-services

It is possible to deploy my own created web service to any of PC without installing any web server app eg:tomcat? I want make it like agent/plug-in in any PC. In order to access the web services i only need to access http://:8080/web_service. Any suggestion about this?