# Can a Java Web Service hosted without deploying it on a server like Tomcat/JBoss?

Tags: java, web-services

As far as I know, one needs Apache Tomcat or App server like JBoss to deploy and run a web service implemented in java.

My manager asked me, isn't there any alternative to deploy a Web service without configuring or setting up Apache Tomcat/JBoss.

I am basically a QA engineer and have some minimal Java programming experience.

We are trying to develop/implement a Java based Web Service for load generation of SMTP messages which can be invoked by test scripts developed using different technologies (QTP, Perl etc.)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292171/deploy-java-web-service-without-using-web-server

Comment: Thanks Zakk. Will check it out

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can run a Webservice simply off the JDK using the [`@WebService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/jws/WebService.html) annotation. It even supports SOAP.

Simple example (taken from [here](http://www.theserverside.de/webservice-in-java/), in german):

Service:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
public class Calculator {
  public long addValues(int val1, int val2) {
    return val1 + val2;
  }
}
```

Initialization code:

```
public class CalculatorServer {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    Calculator server = new Calculator();
    Endpoint endpoint =
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/calculator", server);
  }
}
```

Comment: The article you reference does not address container-less execution at all. Not even close to what this question is about.

Comment: @pap You are right, I have removed the reference. Unfortunately I was unable to find a useful article in english on this subject... Still, this is the way to do it.

Comment: @nfechner - Thanks for the input. Wrote a sample program using javax.ws based on article in IBM DeveloperWorks Portal.

Answer (score 1):

Web services built in java is basically a Java Application with a different data presentation behavior. you can, just then you have to make them up running when the consumer calls a service. This is how we test them in white box manner.

Answer (score 0):

I hope we can, if we use a [BINDING](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-ws-gloss-20021114/#general) protocol as SMTP or CORBA rather than HTTP.

Link : Protocol [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_services_protocol_stack) for Web-services.