# Host a web-service from within a Swing application

Tags: java, .net, swing, web-services

I have to set up a desktop Java client that will communicate with a .NET desktop application. The .NET application exposes its services through a webserver of its own. Rather than have my Java app frequently poll it for data changes, it was suggested that the .NET app contact my Java desktop app via a webservice or similar technique. I am not familiar with web services, but as I understand you would need some sort of web app container such as Tomcat to host it. 
Is there a way to set up a listening socket in my app as a webservice end point without effectively rewriting a webserver from scratch? 
Alternately, are there other or better ways for a .NET desktop application to talk to a Java Swing desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JRE 6 then you can use the `Endpoint.publish()` method to create an in-app server and expose a service.
Refer the simple tutorial in the [link](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jax-ws/create-and-consume-web-service-using-jax-ws/) to see an example of the same.

How the `Endpoint.publish()` works is it internally creates a light weight server and makes the SOAP service available on that location.

Comment: To add to the answer above, I think you should also take a look at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292171/deploy-java-web-service-without-using-web-server)