# Do I need a Java Server (Tomcat, Jetty etc) for an electron-webapp with Java background?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, server, electron

I wanted to create a Java web app with electronJS front-end. Electron would technically communicate with the Java server for loading data. The Server would be responsible for managing users and sending data stored on a database to electron.

I read about web apps that are made with java and the many servers (glasfish, tomcat, etc.) I do not really know if it's needed for my project.

My idea was to create the back-end in Java and host it on a machine that is 24h online. I don't really understand the point of Tomcat etc.

Thank you for your help (:

Comment: how are you planning to access java back-end code, I mean by exposing some API(built in Java) right?

Comment: @MOnkey I read about RESTful applications, it would be a possibility to use it. The idea was to use electron just like a website that communicates with the server.

Comment: you check this, it will help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292171/deploy-java-web-service-without-using-web-server

Comment: if you do not need performance you can go without server as mentioned above but If you need performance (lot of simultaneous request), you will need a container (e.g. Tomcat, etc).

Comment: @MOnkey may I message you privately? I have some questions about this topic. I don't want to do a full conversation in the comments. Could you provide me your email or any kind of messenger like discord?

Comment: Sure, @Mateusz Dettlaff, you can share me your email Id, I will reply you back on the same..

Comment: @MOnkey thank you, my email is mateusz.dettlaff0@gmail.com I will await your message (: